# What happened to "gcm.notification.body" key in FCM extras (bundle data) ? FCM seems to stop sending it?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Before, it seems like the bundle data arriving with the Push Notification from FCM has the following:

```
Before:
{
    "google.c.a.udt": "...",
    "google.sent_time": "1486481416380",
    "gcm.notification.e": "1",
    "google.c.a.c_id": "...",
    "google.c.a.ts": "...",
    "gcm.n.e": "1",
    "google.message_id": "...",
    "gcm.notification.body": "testing 123",
    "google.c.a.e": "1",
    "collapse_key": "..."
}
```

Now, my code seems to be broken because when I look in the key "gcm.notification.body", the key doesn't exist anymore. Here's what I see now:

```
Now
{
    "google.sent_time": "1486481416380",
    "goole.message_id": "...",
}
```

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Was there any change in your payload as well? It might help if you post a sample

Comment: No, payload and everything else have not changed.